# I want my search function to be able to take multiple words rather than just one word, or exact sentence match in my database

Tags: python, django

Here is my search bar function:

`

```
def searchbar(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        search = request.GET["search"],
        deity = Deity.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=search[0])|Q(location__contains=search[0])|Q(alt_name__contains=search[0])|Q(culture__contains=search[0])|Q(religion__contains=search[0])|Q(description__contains=search[0])|Q(pop_culture__contains=search[0])),

        context = {
            "user": User.objects.get(id = request.session['user_id']),
            "deity": deity,
            "search": search[0],
        }
        return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
`
```

My Navbar has a search text box and button, and it searches my entire database for exactly what I put into the search bar (with the exception of capitalization, that doesn't seem to matter). However, if I put a sentence in, it takes whole sentence and searches for it exactly not recognizing the individual words in the search. How can I fix this?

Comment: You're basically going to do what search engines are doing. Checkout [searchrank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchrank) if it's meets your needs

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using SQLite which can't do searchrank like PostgreSQL can.

Answer (score 0):

**SQLite** doesn’t support case-sensitive **LIKE** statements. That's why **contains** acts like **icontains** for SQLite. See the [database notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#substring-matching-and-case-sensitivity) for more information.

And the reason you are not getting the correct result because you are searching for only the first character by using `search[0]`.
So you can try something like this:

```py
deity = Deity.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=search)
                         | Q(alt_name__contains=search)
                         | Q(culture__contains=search)
                         | Q(religion__contains=search)
                         | Q(description__contains=search)
                         | Q(pop_culture__contains=search))
```

If you use `search[0]` instead of `search`, you get `string index out of range` **Exception** if you submit the form without entering anything in the search box. So to play safe always make sure the incoming query isn't empty.

Comment: I forgot to mention that for some reason the "search" variable is returning a tuple. That's why I need the search[0]. In my function if I include print(search) it prints ('query'), but if I print(search[0]) it returns query

Comment: Then add your `search_results.html` file too in your question.